# Recursive Future calls with Dart

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I have this sort of pseudo-code in a `Widget` state (it uses a [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) to display an infinite number variable size cards, cards being loaded page by page):

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_onAfterLayout);
    super.initState();
  }

  _onAfterLayout(_) {
    if (_needNextPage()) {
      _getNextPage();
      _fillPages();
    }
  }

  // a function that fills the screen with cards, calling getNextPage every 500 ms until the screen is full
  _fillPages() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      if (_needNextPage()) {
        _getNextPage();
        _fillPages(); // go recursive
      }
    });
  }

  // a function that checks if a page should be loaded
  bool _needNextPage() {
    ...
  }

  // a function that loads a page from network  
  _getNextPage() {
    if (loading) return;

    loading = true;
    op = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(Context.search(context, results.input)).then((res) {
      loading = false;
      setState(() {
        // add what has been loaded to the current result list, causes rebuilt, etc.
      });
    });
  }
```

This code functionally works, but when I run it in an Android Nexus 10 virtual device with a small page size (it has a big screen, so it needs lots of request to fill an entire page), the whole app just crashes rapidly without any log, information nor stacktrace, and I was wondering if it could be due to my code...

The recursive `_fillPages` smells bad to me, maybe there are better ways, I know there's no [tail recursion optimization](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/29) in Dart so I was wondering if this could cause issues?

Comment: Recursion that goes too deep can run out of stack.  If you want to call a function at regular intervals, you should use [`Timer.periodic`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.2/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html).

Comment: @jamesdlin - ah thanks, I didn't know about Timer.periodic. It sure seems better than what I do now. What would be the effect of recursion? Would it be capable of crashing my application without any notice? Or would that cause a catchable exception (catchable at least in Android Studio console/logcat)?

Comment: I've never tried it in a Dart program, but it's not uncommon for programs that run out of stack space to terminate abruptly.  Having no space left on the stack makes it harder to report errors.